# Batch Prediction Job non-blocking

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am running a Vertex AI batch prediction using the python API.
The function I am using is from the google cloud docs:

```
def create_batch_prediction_job_dedicated_resources_sample(
    key_path,
    project: str,
    location: str,
    model_display_name: str,
    job_display_name: str,
    gcs_source: Union[str, Sequence[str]],
    gcs_destination: str,
    machine_type: str = "n1-standard-2",
    sync: bool = True,
):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path)

# Initilaize an aiplatfrom object
 aiplatform.init(project=project, location=location, credentials=credentials)

# Get a list of Models by Model name
 models = aiplatform.Model.list(filter=f'display_name="{model_display_name}"')
 model_resource_name = models[0].resource_name

# Get the model
 my_model = aiplatform.Model(model_resource_name)

 batch_prediction_job = my_model.batch_predict(
    job_display_name=job_display_name,
    gcs_source=gcs_source,
    gcs_destination_prefix=gcs_destination,
    machine_type=machine_type,
    sync=sync,
)

 #batch_prediction_job.wait_for_resource_creation()
 batch_prediction_job.wait()

 print(batch_prediction_job.display_name)
 print(batch_prediction_job.resource_name)
 print(batch_prediction_job.state)
 return batch_prediction_job

datetime_today = datetime.datetime.now()
model_display_name = 'test_model'
key_path = 'vertex_key.json'
project = 'my_project'
location = 'asia-south1'
job_display_name = 'batch_prediction_' + str(datetime_today)
model_name = '1234'
gcs_source = 'gs://my_bucket/Cleaned_Data/user_item_pairs.jsonl'
gcs_destination = 'gs://my_bucket/prediction'

create_batch_prediction_job_dedicated_resources_sample(key_path,project,location,model_display_name,job_display_name,
                                                      gcs_source,gcs_destination)
```

OUTPUT:

```
92 current state:
JobState.JOB_STATE_RUNNING
INFO:google.cloud.aiplatform.jobs:BatchPredictionJob projects/my_project/locations/asia-south1/batchPredictionJobs/37737350127597649
```

The above output is being printed on the terminal over and over after every few seconds.

The issue that I have is that the python program calling this function keeps on running until it is force stopped. I have tried both `batch_prediction_job.wait()` & `batch_prediction_job.wait_for_resource_creation()` with the same results.

How do I start a batch_prediction_job without waiting for it to complete and terminating the program just after the job has be created?

Comment: Checking the documentation of the `batch_predict()` method it says: `Creates a batch prediction job using this Model and outputs prediction results to the provided destination prefix in the specified predictions_format.` So I understand you don't need the wait functions. After call the `batch_predict()` the job is already started. Run it without the waits and check is the jod is created on the terminal.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The job is created without the wait function call. But the terminal is still blocked and the three print commands are still executing every few seconds.

Comment: Are you calling it from another function or script ? I dont see why it's on loop repeating the 3 prints based on the code you have posted.

Comment: I am just calling this function with the same scripts using the parameters needed. I'll edit the question with the complete script

Comment: Could you please the output with the indicated issue

Comment: The output is the the three print statements before the return in the function are getting executed every few seconds, atleast that's what I think. I'll update the question with the actual output as well.

Comment: Call the job with the flag `sync=True` and just print the job with `print(batch_predict_job)` an example:  ```batch_predict_job = model.batch_predict( ...
    gcs_source=gcs_input_uri,
    gcs_destination_prefix=BUCKET_NAME,
    sync=True,
)

print(batch_predict_job)```

Comment: It is still the same behaviour. I even tried to print a random string just after the model.batch_predict and that print is not getting executed. So, it seems the control is not passing prom the batch_predict to the next statement.

Answer (score 0):

I gave you the wrong instruction on the comments, change the parameter `sync=False` and the function should return just after be executed.

> Whether this function call should be synchronous (wait for pipeline run to finish before terminating) or asynchronous (return immediately)

sync=False

```py
def create_batch_prediction_job_dedicated_resources_sample(
# ...
    sync: bool = False,
):
```

##### UPDATE - Adding more details:

[Check here my notebook code](https://github.com/ewertonvsilva/stackoverflow/blob/main/70938078/Batch_Prediction.ipynb) where I tested it and its working:
You have to change the `sync=False` **AND** remove/comment the following print lines:

```py
#batch_prediction_job.wait()
#print(batch_prediction_job.display_name)
#print(batch_prediction_job.resource_name)
#print(batch_prediction_job.state)
```

Your code edited:

```py
def create_batch_prediction_job_dedicated_resources_sample(
    key_path,
    project: str,
    location: str,
    model_display_name: str,
    job_display_name: str,
    gcs_source: Union[str, Sequence[str]],
    gcs_destination: str,
    machine_type: str = "n1-standard-2",
    sync: bool = False,
):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(key_path)

# Initilaize an aiplatfrom object
 aiplatform.init(project=project, location=location, credentials=credentials)

# Get a list of Models by Model name
 models = aiplatform.Model.list(filter=f'display_name="{model_display_name}"')
 model_resource_name = models[0].resource_name

# Get the model
 my_model = aiplatform.Model(model_resource_name)

 batch_prediction_job = my_model.batch_predict(
    job_display_name=job_display_name,
    gcs_source=gcs_source,
    gcs_destination_prefix=gcs_destination,
    machine_type=machine_type,
    sync=sync,
)


 return batch_prediction_job

datetime_today = datetime.datetime.now()
model_display_name = 'test_model'
key_path = 'vertex_key.json'
project = '<my_project_name>'
location = 'asia-south1'
job_display_name = 'batch_prediction_' + str(datetime_today)
model_name = '1234'
gcs_source = 'gs://<my_bucket_name>/Cleaned_Data/user_item_pairs.jsonl'
gcs_destination = 'gs://<my_bucket_name>/prediction'

create_batch_prediction_job_dedicated_resources_sample(key_path,
                         project,location,
                         model_display_name,
                         job_display_name,
                         gcs_source,
                         gcs_destination,
                         sync=False,)
```

**Results** `sync=False`:
[image]
**Results** `sync=True`:
[image]

Comment: Even with the sync parameter being False, the same statements as mentioned in the OUTPUT above is being printed over and over.

Comment: Hi @Tarique, have you removed the print lines ? Its require. You must remove the prints and call the function with `sync=False`. I have updated the answer with the correct code base on yours, and also the print of my testes with it working.

Comment: I still get the same behaviour. I am running it through VSCode and the terminal is blocked with status updates every few seconds as shown above.